# How to use private static member variable of abstract type

Tags: c++, static, private, abstract

I am trying to declare a private static member variable of an abstract type. The code:

```
class AbstractClass{
public:
    virtual double operator()() = 0;
};

class ThisOneContainsIt{
private:
    static AbstractClass var; //this does not work
    static AbstractClass & var; //this seems to work, but...
}

//my .cpp
AbstractClass & ThisOneContainsIt::var; //...this does not work either
```

Now I ran out of ideas. I am pretty sure this must be somehow possible - I could always delete the `= 0` to make the class non-abstract, but that's not what I really want to do.

Comment: You have to initialize references.  What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: what means 'does not work'?

Comment: XY-problem? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Abstract class called AbstractClass cannot be instantiated because it is abstract.  Hence, when you try to instantiate it, the compiler complains.

Comment: You need a class that has the `AbstractClass` as a parent class and inherits from it. That is the point of having an Abstract Class in the first place.

Comment: You can declare a pointer to `AbstractClass` and initialize it null (which is pretty much the only option here). Note that `ThisOneContainsIt` is also abstract because you didn't override the base class' pure function so trying to instantiate it will also fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't instantiate an abstract class.  You have to derive a class from it and override the pure virtual methods.  You can then instantiate that derived class, and use the created instance to initialize your abstract class reference :

```
class AbstractClass
{
    public:
        virtual double operator()() = 0;
};

class DerivedClass : public AbstractClass
{
    public:
        double operator()() override { return 0.0; }
};

class ThisOneContainsIt
{
    private:
        static DerivedClass d;

        static AbstractClass &var;
};

DerivedClass ThisOneContainsIt::d; 

AbstractClass &ThisOneContainsIt::var(d);
```

---

I don't know why you would want to do something like that, though.  You might as well do it like this :

```
class ThisOneContainsIt
{
    private:
        static DerivedClass var;
};

DerivedClass ThisOneContainsIt::var;
```